# How to retrieve workflow attribute values from workflow table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a situation where in I need to take the values from table column which has data based on one of the column in same table.
There are two column values like that which is required to compare with another table.

Scenario:

Column 1 query:

```
SELECT text_value
          FROM WF_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
         WHERE name LIKE 'ORDER_ID' --AND number_value IS NOT NULL
               AND Item_type LIKE 'ABC'
```

this query returns 14 unique records

Column 2 query:

```
SELECT number_value
          FROM WF_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
         WHERE name LIKE 'Source_ID' --AND number_value IS NOT NULL
               AND Item_type LIKE 'ABC'
```

this also returns 14 records

and order_id of column 1 query is associated with source_id of column 2 query  using this two column values i want to compare 14 records combined order_id, source_id with another table column i.e. Sales_tbl
columns sal_order_id, sal_source_id

Sample Data from WF_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES:

*Note: same data in the sales_tbl table but order_id is sal_order_id and sal_source_id*

Order_id

204994 205000 205348 198517 198176 196856 204225 205348 203510 206528 196886 198971 194076 197940

Source_id

92262138 92261783 92262005 92262615 92374992 92375051 92374948 92375000 92375011 92336793 92374960 92691360 92695445 92695880

Desired O/p based on comparison:

[image]

Please help me in writing the query

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB I have updated the sample date and desired o/p